# Error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart, indexing

```
(Edit:  I have 3 files
main , trending and text. Let me show them.) I am showing you 2 of them here - where the mainly important portions are.
```

I think the problem is within 'trending' page where trending[index] is not accepting as String. The api is from tmdb which is a list of maps and has 'poster path'. Donot know what the problem is.

```
Main => 

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        loadmovies();
        super.initState();
      }
      List trendingmovies = [];
      List topratedmovieslist = [];
      List tvlist = [];
      final String apikey = '974ecf335095695927b80cb92fbe6200';
      final readaccesstoken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI5NzRlY2YzMzUwOTU2OTU5MjdiODBjYjkyZmJlNjIwMCIsInN1YiI6IjYzMzAwZmJkYWJkYWZjMDA3Y2Q5OWRkZCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.LZkUXKdyN5YCWJcfV6wYLVejGvYp22BzAQowBUWe5Ys';
    
      loadmovies() async{
        final tmdb = TMDB(
          ApiKeys(apikey, readaccesstoken),
          logConfig: const ConfigLogger(
            showLogs: true,//must be true than only all other logs will be shown
            showErrorLogs: true,
          ),);
          Map result = await tmdb.v3.trending.getTrending();
          Map topratedmovies = await tmdb.v3.movies.getTopRated();
          Map tv = await tmdb.v3.tv.getTopRated();
          setState(() {
            trendingmovies =  result['results'];
            topratedmovieslist =  topratedmovies['results'];
            tvlist =  tv['results'];
    
          });
        print(trendingmovies);
        print(topratedmovieslist);
        print(tvlist);
    
    
    
    
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const modified_text(text:'Film Library', color: Colors.white70, size: 20,
          ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              TrendingMovies(trending: [trendingmovies],)
    
            ],
          ),
    
        );
      }
    }


Edit: This is the trending file. I have noted that initialized list doesn't contain poster_path like with tmdb but the main file has extracted it to a list.
  


Trending ->
import 'package:film_library/utils/text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class TrendingMovies extends StatelessWidget {
  const TrendingMovies({Key? key, required this.trending}) : super(key: key);
  final List trending;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(

        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,


        children: [
          const modified_text (text:'Trending Movies', size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(height: 300,
            child: ListView.builder(itemCount: trending.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return InkWell(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 140,
                  child: Column(
                    children:  [
                      Container(
                        height: 200,
                        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                         image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(
                             'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + trending[index] ['poster_path']))

                        )
                      ),
                      modified_text(text: trending[index]['title'], color: Colors.brown, size: 20,)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          )
        ],

      ),

    );

  }
}
```

Edit: There is text file as well but it is nothing but just used as some Font class. I have created model class like - List trending but it too says that - Error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Trending Movies', and shows error on same poster_path. Maybe the syntax is wrong with calling it as @jacksparrow, did while it doesnt show the error here with [index] ['poster_path'] but that one of the title.

Comment: How does the trending list look? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: you need to convert by `jsonDecode()` the trending list but im not sure, provide full snippet and trending list

Comment: according to your code, the "trending" supposed to be a list of maps, and each map should contain "poster_path", but that's apparently not what the "trending" list's content is.

Comment: @tareqalbeesh yes, you got that right. It is from tmdb api and it is a list of maps. Check the code on the question. I have edited it. There is main and the previous one present. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that please create model class from json response of your Trending movies API and then create list of trending movies using that model like as below :

```
List<TrendingMovies> trending ;
```

Comment: same issue as @jacksparrow

Answer (score 0):

It is better to fetch data from API by making **model class** and **fromJson** method of that particular json response. It makes more easier to understand use data in it.

```html
import 'package:film_library/utils/text.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TrendingMovies extends StatelessWidget {
  const TrendingMovies({Key? key, required this.trending}) : super(key: key);
 List<TrendingMovies> trendingMoviesList ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const modified_text (text:'Trending Movies', size: 30, color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: trending.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
final trendingMovie= trendingMoviesList[index];
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 140,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 200,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${trendingMovie.poster_path}"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          modified_text(text: trendingMovie.title, color: Colors.brown, size: 20,)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax of 'poster_path' like that shows error. Maybe it doesnt consider calling it like that.